# How to make multiple read more buttons produced from while loop using php in single page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to fetch data from database and put a read more and read less button on each of them. However only the first read more works fine and the rest of them don't. The first read more shows the fetched data but when I click on the rest of the read more buttons, they change to read less but doesn't show the fetched data from the database.

Note: without the read more buttons, all the data are perfectly fetched from the database. i.e if i don't put display:none to my .more class, all data are displayed perfectly.

[How to make multiple read more buttons in same page using one jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955285/how-to-make-multiple-read-more-buttons-in-same-page-using-one-jquery)

I have tried to follow the code example given in the above link.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".rm", function() {
   
     if ($(this).text() == "... Read More") 
     {
 $(this).text("Read Less");
        $(this).parent().children(".more").slideDown();
     } 
     else 
     {
 $(this).text("... Read More");
        $(this).parent().children(".more").slideUp();
     }
    
    });
```

```css
.more{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
   <?php 

    $query= "SELECT * FROM doctors ORDER BY doc_id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $na = "Not Available";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
 <div class="single-doctor mb-4 mb-lg-0">
              
    <div class="content-area">
      <div class="doctor-name text-center">
         <h3><?php echo  $row['doc_name']; ?></h3>
         <h6>Expertise : <?php echo  $row['expertise']; ?></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="doctor-text text-center">
        <p> <b>Qualification: </b><?php if(empty($row['qualification'])) { echo $na;}
     else echo $row['qualification']; ?><br/>
     <b>Phone: </b><?php if(empty($row['contact_no'])) { echo $na;}
     else echo $row['contact_no']; ?><br/>
                                    
            <span class="more">
        <b>Designation: </b><?php if(empty($row['designation'])) { echo $na;}
        else echo $row['designation']; ?><br/>
        <b>Organization: </b><?php if(empty($row['organization'])) { echo $na;}
         else echo $row['organization']; ?><br/>
         <b>Chamber: </b><?php if(empty($row['chamber'])) { echo $na;}
          else echo $row['chamber']; ?><br/>
   <b>Location: </b><?php if(empty($row['location'])) { echo $na;}
   else echo $row['location']; ?><br/>
   <b>More: </b><?php if(empty($row['education'])) { echo $na;}
   else echo $row['education']; ?><br/>
   <b>Website: </b><?php if(empty($row['website'])) { echo $na;}
   else echo  $row['website']; ?>
      </span>

      <a class="rm">... Read More</a>
   </p>
       </div>
   </div>

       </div>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the example, the approach I would take would be to use the height of the hidden div or the number of lines (could also derive the height from this) or a mixture of both, and basically create "anchors" as you are going down through multiple "Read More" clicks, while also displaying the "Read Less" which could either go up one click or return to the top.